# (DONE) Why is question about reorganizations closed as Off-Topic?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Are workplace reorganizations that result in a change in job duties without employee consent a violation of the original job contract?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147989/are-workplace-reorganizations-that-result-in-a-change-in-job-duties-without-empl)

To me, the question seems clear and has a clear answer.

This is something any good HR rep or anyone who has been through reorgs could answer. It does not require a law degree for an answer. It's like many other questions that were answered here.

So to me, it makes no sense that it was closed.

I voted to re-open. I invite others to do the same.

Comment: seems reasonable... vtro

Comment: Agreed, its open now.